"She was a curious mixture, part grand lady, part wild child." — Is "part grand lady, part wild child" an appositive, supplement and adjunct?
oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com:
(1) She was a curious mixture, part grand lady, part wild child.
my parse:
"Part grand lady" is a noun phrase.
"Part wild child" is a noun phrase.
"Part grand lady, part wild child" is a coordinate structure.
"Part grand lady, part wild child" is the appositive to the noun "mixture".
"Part grand lady, part wild child" is the supplement to the noun "mixture".
"Part grand lady, part wild child" is an adjunct.
"A curious mixture, part grand lady, part wild child" is a noun phrase with the head "mixture".
Is my parse correct?
If not, then could you please show me all mistakes I've made?

Why does that belong here in ELU, rather than in English Language Learners, please?
Why not remove or correct the punctuation?
I believe '… a curious mixture, part grand lady, part wild child…' is inadequate, and drags the Question down with it.
Many will doubt this and in my view, with no better punctuation '… a curious mixture, part (anything)…' invalidates itself. It needs at least a semi– if not a full colon.
If it does belong here, will you go back and re-phrase the exposition to take account of my views?

@RobbieGoodwin 1) ELL's and ELU's help centers say nothing about syntactic analysis. So if you want a clarification, you may raise this issue on ELU's or ELL's meta site. At this moment, I know for sure, if you ask to parse something on ELL, you will be told by their members that such questions are more appropriate for ELU. That's why I asked the original question here and will continue to do so as to other similar ones. 2) The punctuation was taken from the dictionary. That is, they think their variant of it is possible. So the phrase "remove or correct it" is at least weird.

@RobbieGoodwin One more time: The rules must be written in the Help Center. Neither ELL's nor ELU's Help Center says anything about syntactic analysis. So you just can't assert where such questions should be placed. The only thing you can do is to ask for a clarification about it on the meta sites. Because I'm definitely not that man who can help you to solve this problem.

"Part grand lady" is a noun phrase.
"Part wild child" is a noun phrase.

Yes, both can take determiner one, so it seems they are.


She was a curious mixture, one part grand lady, one part wild child.

"Part grand lady, part wild child" is a coordinate structure.

Yes: can be reversed, can add in coordinator and.


She was a curious mixture, part wild child, part grand lady.
She was a curious mixture, part grand lady, and part wild child.

"Part grand lady, part wild child" is the appositive to the noun "mixture".
"Part grand lady, part wild child" is the supplement to the noun "mixture".

Not exactly, appositives are between grammatically parallel units, so
it's the noun phrase a curious mixture that the coordination
part grand lady, part wild child would be an appositive to.
Though, part grand lady, part wild child can also be fronted, so may simply be a supplement to the
whole clause she was a curious mixture.


Part grand lady, part wild child, she was a curious mixture.

"Part grand lady, part wild child" is an adjunct.

Yes, supplements are always adjuncts.

"A curious mixture, part grand lady, part wild child" is a noun phrase with the head "mixture".

If part grand lady, part wild child is a supplement, then by definition it's not part of the noun phrase. It either has She was a curious mixture or a curious mixture as an anchor.


(1) She was a curious mixture, part grand lady, part wild child.
Phrases in apposition, e.g. “It was John, my brother” are distinguished by
(i) having the noun phrases reversible without significant loss of meaning:
It was my brother, John.
(ii)    having one of the phrases omitted without significant loss of meaning:
It was John.
It was my brother.
Thus
She was a curious mixture, part grand lady, part wild child.
She was part grand lady, part wild child, a curious mixture. “part grand lady, part wild child” and “a curious mixture” are each descriptors of the other.
She was a curious mixture.
She was part grand lady, part wild child.
You can see "It was John, my brother" as a reduced relative clause: "It was John, who was my brother" but this does not prevent it from being termed "in apposition":
She was a curious mixture, which was part grand lady, part wild child.
Edit to clarify the PoS of "part" in the NPs "part grand lady", "part wild child."
I rather think that here, "part" is an attributive noun (i.e. having an adjectival function and being uncountable) which thus accounts for its being anarthrous.
However:
OED entry for part (Adjective);
When preceding a single noun, verb, adjective, or participle, the word takes on the characteristics of a prefix, and is commonly hyphenated. However, it is frequently used more than once in a sentence, forming a kind of correlative construction.
Partial; that is (something) in part but not in full.
In certain compounds often with the sense ‘part of’ (cf. part-time adj. & adv., part-way adv., etc.).
Recorded earliest in part payment n.
1496 Item,..in part payment of theking of the chapell..with spule, iiij li. xij d.
in T. Dickson, Accounts of Treasurer of Scotland (1877) vol. I. 279
1833 An excursion of part business, part pleasure. H. Martineau, French Wines & Politics i. 1
2000 If you think a pink mink dress is puke-making, imagine how much worse it is when a dress is part-mink, part-wool. Sunday Times 23 July (Style section) 17/2

Various sources claim that 'part' is a (flat) adverb in say


The television producer today has to be part news person, part educator.

part [4] {adverb} used as [ADVERB noun, ADVERB adjective]
If you say that something is part one thing, part another, you mean
that it is to some extent the first thing and to some extent the
second thing.

Perhaps this sort of partitive (eg 'half' in 'half man, half beast') needs a different POS tag.
However, I'd agree that in

She was a curious mixture, part grand lady, part wild child.

'part grand lady, part wild child' is an expository parenthetical in apposition to 'a curious mixture'. A colon could be used instead of the comma. An appositive demands that the strings in apposition be of the same type, so I'd say the parenthetical is nominal.
[Collins; re-ordered]
Ning Zhang, in Coordinate Structures, CUP, writes:

In a coordination construction, which is universally available, two or
more syntactic constituents are combined, with or without an overt
coordinator.

So 'part A, part B' is a coordinate structure just like 'part/ly A and part/ly B'.
I'd not over-analyse.

You wrote: "An appositive demands that the strings in apposition be of the same type, so I'd say the parenthetical is nominal." This sentence is unclear to me. Does it mean you think "part grand lady, part wild child" is a noun phrase? Thanks.

It behaves as a noun phrase in this structure. I'll not commit myself further; people have stipulative definitions involving further tests that are arguably subjectively chosen.

If "part grand lady, part wild child" is a noun phrase, then it has two heads: “lady” and “child”. I've always thought a constituent couldn’t have more than one head. Am I wrong? Thanks.

It's clearly two coordinated elements. I'm saying that 'a curious mixture' and 'part grand lady, part wild child' are complements in apposition, the latter a coordinate structure.

I asked about the head of "part grand lady, part wild child". If you say it's a noun phrase, then it must have a head. What head does it have? Thanks.

I said it behaves like a noun phrase. One could say it's pointless trying to analyse what appears to be a relict of 'She was a curious mixture; she was in part a grand lady and in part a wild child.'

I don't understand what "it behaves like a noun phrase" means. Does it mean: "part grand lady, part wild child" behaves like a noun phrase but it's not a noun phrase ???

According to this blog post, part is a noun which does not require a determiner or article here; Geoffrey Pullum characterized such phrases as part man, part animal as "idiomatic constructions with anarthrous nominals", and CGEL seems to broadly agree, although not all sources do.

It behaves to some extent like a noun phrase. If G Pullum can describe such strings as 'idiomatic constructions with [covertly coordinated] anarthrous nominals', that's where I'll stick. Traditional labels don't work well in some cases.

@EdwinAshworth By the way, G Pullum wrote a wrong collocation: "idiomatic constructions with anarthrous nominals". That is, he implies there are also non-anarthrous nominals. But all nominals, by his own definition, must be always anarthrous.

@Lovii But all nominals, by his own definition, must be always anarthrous Far be it from me to support Pullam, but you have misunderstood what he is saying. He is saying that the nouns (usually singular and countable) are used without an article: This is unusual.
